# Residue Theorem Problems

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you integrate:

$$\int \dfrac{\cos(2θ)}{1−2a\cos(θ)+a^2} dθ,    (−1 < a < 1)$$

So far, I have substituted $z=e^{iθ} $and transformed the above integral in terms of z and a. But I couldn't figure out how to get the two residues at z=0 and z=a.

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you intend to use the residue theorem, you need to have some integration limits.  Typically, these limits are such that the complex integral is about a closed contour.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $b,c,d,e,f$ be constants, then we can reduce the function to be inetegrated as:

$$I(\theta)=\frac{\cos(2θ)}{1−2a\cos(θ)+a^2}=e(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta))+f(\cos(\theta)-i \sin(\theta))$$
$$+b+\frac{c}{a-\cos(\theta)-i \sin(\theta)}+\frac{d}{a-\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta)}$$

The solution for $b,c,d,e,f$ are:

$$b=\frac{a^2}{1-a^2},c=d=-\frac{1+a^4}{2a(1-a^2)},e=f=-\frac{1}{2a}$$